# Querying Androids ContactsContract in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having a bit of a trouble trying to query ContactsContract in an android app written in Kotlin. Android studio gives errors from unresolved references for example from ContactsContract.Contacts._ID. Does anyone know the right way to query these in Kotlin?

Comment: This was fixed in Kotlin 1.0 Beta 1, the issue KT-3180

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open bug in Kotlin. Please refer to: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3180.

For now you could use Java to access such fields as a workaround:

```
public class ContactsSupport {
    public static interface BaseColumns {
        public static final String _ID = ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID;
        public static final String _COUNT = ContactsContract.RawContacts._COUNT;
    }
}
```

So you can write `ContactsSupport.BaseColumns._ID` in Kotlin.

Comment: This was fixed in Kotlin 1.0 Beta 1, the issue KT-3180